# handlin Net.WebResponse with select statment in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, try-catch, httpwebresponse

i've the following function which gets html or xml source from some page, when there is 403 exception i found out the code doesn't continue to the select statement

```
   Public Function GetPageHTML(ByVal URL As String, _
        Optional ByVal TimeoutSeconds As Integer = 10) _
        As String
        ' Retrieves the HTML from the specified URL,
        ' using a default timeout of 10 seconds
        Dim objRequest As Net.WebRequest
        Dim objResponse As Net.WebResponse
        Dim objStreamReceive As System.IO.Stream
        Dim objEncoding As System.Text.Encoding
        Dim objStreamRead As System.IO.StreamReader


        ' Setup our Web request
        objRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
        objRequest.Timeout = TimeoutSeconds * 5000
        ' Retrieve data from request

Try
        objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse 'some times it gives an error server unavailable 503

        Select Case CType(objResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusCode
            Case Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout
                Return "BadRequest"
            Case 403
                Return "BadRequest"
            Case Net.HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout
                Return "BadRequest"
            Case Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                Return "BadRequest"
            Case Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                Return "BadRequest"
            Case Net.HttpStatusCode.OK

                objStreamReceive = objResponse.GetResponseStream
                objEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding( _
                    "utf-8")

                objStreamRead = New System.IO.StreamReader( _
                    objStreamReceive, objEncoding)
                ' Set function return value

                GetPageHTML = objStreamRead.ReadToEnd()
                ' Check if available, then close response
                If Not objResponse Is Nothing Then
                    objResponse.Close()
                End If
            Case Else
                MsgBox("Case Else")

        End Select
catch
Return ""
End Try
    End Function
```

so how can i fix this? the debugger shows the exception in this line

```
objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse 'some times it gives an error server unavailable 503 or 403
```

so it doesnt go to the select statment

also second try with the same problem, it doesnt catch the error and doesnt show the exception message
[image]

Comment: Are you in debug mode? You might have Visual Studio set to trap all exceptions, regardless of if you have a catch clause. Try continuing execution and see if the catch clause gets hit.

Comment: i tried, i set a message box in the `Case Net.HttpStatusCode.OK` and it showed , but when i get the 403 error it doesn't access `Case Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden` and it shows the exception in the debugger

Comment: The exception is occuring before the Case Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden is reached, so the Case will not execute. I'm talking about the Catch clause - try placing a breakpoint on MsgBox(ex.Message) and continue execution after the exception, and see if the new breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: yes it seems to get hit, and seems to work fine but why do i get the exception on the debugger when there is try statment, the code works fine when i click the debuggung button after the exception, and it returns "BadRequest" as expected

Comment: nevermind i tried deploying the application and its working fine!, but how can i fix this on the debugger?

Comment: I think it's an option in Visual Studio, but I can't seem to find it at the moment...

Comment: Found it! Debug menu, then hit Exceptions. Uncheck the exceptions in the "Thrown" column that you want to let the program catch automatically without stopping the debugger.